# Neo4j 3.0.3 fail to start

Tags: neo4j

on OSX
I was working with 3.0.0, upgraded to 3.0.3 and receive this message when launching a new local database.

"Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@bfdf32a' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
"

I uninstalled both, deleted .neo4j file and reinstalled 3.0.3 -> same

Any idea what to do?

Best

Comment: Not sure about OSX specifics, but on Win10 when I get this error it usually is because I haven't ran the program as administrator.

Comment: @Sevle strange, I'm getting the same error, but I'm on Windows 10 and have run it as administrator.

Comment: seems to be solved with 3.1.0-M04